# JAR convertido em exe não abre após ser transferido via socket

Tags: java, socket

Tenho um programa JAR que converti pra EXE com o Launch4J.
O EXE funciona normal, porém quando eu tento transferir este arquivo via socket ele simplesmente não abre mais com 2 clicks.

Se eu usar um "java -jar arquivo.exe" ele abre normal. Só não abre clicando duas vezes em cima. Alguém tem alguma idéia do que pode ser?

Não acho que seja problema na transferência, mas fica aqui as classes que a realizam.

Cliente:

```
private void receiveVersion(String version) {
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    InputStream ins = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    Socket client = null;
    try {
        String host = (Constants.SERVER_HOST.contains("localhost") ? "localhost" : Constants.SERVER_HOST);
        client = new Socket(host, 9780);
        //Abre os devidos canais de comuicação
        out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        ins = client.getInputStream();
        dis = new DataInputStream(ins);
        //Envia a versao para realizar o download
        out.writeUTF(version);
        //Recebe o tamanho do arquivo
        long tamanho = dis.readLong();
        //FileOutputStream para salvar o arquivo
        File path = new File(".");
        File original = new File(path, "MEUJAR.exe");
        if (original.exists()) {
            original.delete();
            original = null;
        }
        System.out.println("<<< VersionUpdaterClient - ARQUIVO SENDO CRIADO EM " + path.getAbsolutePath() + " >>>");
        File finalFile = new File(path, "MEUJAR.exe");

        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(finalFile));
        //Recebe os bytes do server
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        //Envia os bytes
        Integer leitura = null;
        Integer count = 0;
        do{
            leitura = ins.read(buffer, 0 , buffer.length);
            count += leitura;
            bos.write(buffer, 0, leitura);
            bos.flush();
        } while(leitura != -1 && count < tamanho);
        bos.close();
        System.out.println("<<< VersionUpdaterClient - ARQUIVO CRIADO COM SUCESSO " + finalFile + " " + finalFile.length() + " >>>");
        //Desktop.getDesktop().open( new File( "MEUJAR.exe" ));  ====> Também não funciona
        new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "MEUJAR.exe").start(); // Assim funciona
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (client != null) {
                client.close();
            }
            if (ins != null) {
                ins.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (dis != null) {
                dis.close();
            }
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Servidor:

```
private void sendVersion(Socket client) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream os = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream dis;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            try {
                dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                os = client.getOutputStream();
                dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                String actualVersion = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("<<< VersionUpdaterService - INICIADO ENVIO DE VERSAO "+actualVersion+" PARA " + client.getInetAddress());
                File file = new File(VERSIONS_PATH + actualVersion + "\\MEUJAR.exe");
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

                //Envia o tamanho do arquivo
                dos.writeLong(file.length());
                dos.flush();

                //Cria um buffer
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
                //Envia dados
                Integer leitura = null;
                do {
                    leitura = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    System.out.flush();
                    if (leitura != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, leitura);
                    }
                    os.flush();
                } while (leitura != -1);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (os != null) {
                        os.close();
                    }
                    if (dos != null) {
                        dos.close();
                    }
                    if (client != null) {
                        client.close();
                    }
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Executando somente `arquivo.exe` ele abre?

Comment: Abre sim.
Só para de abrir quando transfiro ele.

Comment: Quando você diz transferir por via socket, é para um computador diferente? Ou é pro mesmo computador a partir do qual foi enviado? Como ele abre usando a linha de comando é provavelmente erro na configuração do caminho para o jre na hora de criar o executavel (desde que funcione no mesmo computador).

Comment: To testando para o mesmo computador.
E descobri uma coisa mais estranha... Esse arquivo transferido que não abre com o duplo clique só não funciona se eu deixar no Desktop. Se eu jogar ele em uma pasta, abre com 2 clicks... Vai entender.